# Upgraded to 20.04 and can't install gnome-control-center

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, gnome-control-center

I've just upgraded my ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 and immediately realized that I could not open settings. I read that the problem has to do with gnome-control-center, but when I use

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk25 (>= 3.18.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese8 (>= 3.28.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgoa-backend-1.0-1 (>= 3.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-online-accounts (>= 3.25.3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-user-docs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then, I found this discussion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) and tried to follow each presented solution to fix this unmet dependencies problem. Unfortunately, nothing worked.

My next attempt was to follow this instructions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/g8fv4f/the_following_packages_have_unmet_dependencies_i/). So I started adding each package dependecy in my `sudo apt install` command, and then new dependecies appeared and a repeted the process. My final command was

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-online-accounts gnome-control-center gnome-user-docs libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 ubuntu-docs yelp libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl20 gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 libgl1 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgl1-mesa-dri libglvnd0 libglx0 libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0
```

for which the output was

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglapi-mesa is already the newest version (20.2.0~kisak1~b).
libglvnd0 is already the newest version (1.3.2-1~kisak~b).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 1.3.2-1~kisak~b is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) but 20.2.0~kisak1~b is to be installed
 libglx-mesa0 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) but 20.2.0~kisak1~b is to be installed
 libglx0 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 1.3.2-1~kisak~b is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After that, I get the same output if I add `libglvnd0` and `libglapi-mesa` at the end of my `sudo apt install` command. I don't know what to do next and I am kind of desperate and very afraid of rebooting my computer.

Comment: Have you checked about the broken packages, Synaptic package manager should list them.  My fix was to install unity desktop, but maybe not of your liking.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Actually, I've just fixed it. For these last dependencies that ending with "but ... is to be installed" I removed them and installed again using aptitude. I wasn't being able to remove them using apt but aptitude worked just fine. I will add an answer to my question explaining better what I did.

Answer (score 8):

I solved my problem using the `aptitude` to remove and reinstall the two unmet dependencies `libglvnd0` and `libglapi-mesa`. I was not being able to delete/install them using apt or apt-get, but `aptitude` worked pretty well. After that, I kept the same process of adding the new dependencies that eventually appeared to the `sudo apt install` command and reinstalling those more problematic when they appeared.

Long story short:

- if the unmet dependence has a description like this:

  gnome-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk25 (>= 3.18.0) **but it is not going to be installed**

use `sudo apt install package1 package2` to install all dependencies **simultaneously**; it won`t work if you install them one by one.

- else, if the description is like this:

  libgl1 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) **but** 1.3.2-1~kisak~b **is to be installed**

use `aptitude` to reinstall them. The following commands install `aptitude`, remove the problematic package and install it, respectively.

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude remove package
sudo aptitude install package
```

After solving this problem I immediately got another one. I tried to reboot my PC but it never reached the login screen. I must have delete some important packages accidentally when I was testing solutions. I fixed this problem by launching the recovery mode, opening the root shell and typing

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: thanks, after dig a lot of solution, finally I can get the solution for my problem, thanks

Comment: on my machine the issue were conflicting distros in apt sources. few were yami, few lunar

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same, resolved by
'sudo apt remove xxx' any package that has a "but" in the sentence as they are newer than expected 'sudo apt install gnome-control-center'